# Flyway "migrate" command can't find current schema (SQL Server)

Tags: flyway

I just upgraded to version 2.1.1, and now I'm seeing a strange error - the migrate command fails with a Flyway exception when I run it against a database on our staging and production database servers, but it works fine against our development server.

This is the debug output when it fails:

```
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: C:\workspace\flyway\bin\..\jars\jtds-1.2.7.jar
DEBUG: Database: Microsoft SQL Server 10.0
DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: true
DEBUG: Schema: dbo
DEBUG: Schema [dbo] already exists. Skipping schema creation.
DEBUG: No upgrade to the Flyway 2.0 format necessary for metadata table [dbo].[schema_version]
DEBUG: No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.0.2 format necessary
DEBUG: No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.1 format necessary
ERROR: Unexpected error
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Current schema not set for connection! Check your database configuration!
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupport.getCurrentSchema(DbSupport.java:79)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:855)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:815)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1177)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:815)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:118)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

It's clearly finding the schema when checking the metadata table, but then for some reason doesn't believe it's set later on.

The schema itself is defined in the flyway.properties file -

```
flyway.schemas=dbo
```

I can't find any differences between dev and staging/prod that would cause this error.

If it makes a difference, this is happening after a "clean" and "init"...

Any suggestions for where to look?

**EDIT (for future people with the same issue):**  Axel was correct about the login not having a default schema on the servers exhibiting the problem.  When I run

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()
```

on our DEV server, I get "dbo" back; but when I run that on our ACC And PROD servers, I just get "NULL" back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it seems the default schema for the user on the systems affected is null.

Please file an issue and I'll remove this check in the next version.

In the mean time, you should be OK if you give your users a default schema.

Comment: We're using integrated security with a domain group, and SQL Server doesn't allow you to set a default schema for a group (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/7d46a024-7ed5-4c9b-b091-3640dc04f5a1/).